# Add Percentage after Sorting by Year and Quarter MySQL

Tags: mysql

The following query returns order totals for the Year and Quarter. I would also like to have the value stated as a percentage of the total spend.

```
SELECT DATABASE() AS PURCHASING_Total_PO_Value_By_Year, 
YEAR(order_headers.created_at) AS Year, 
QUARTER(order_headers.created_at) AS Quarter, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(order_headers.id)) AS Orders, 
SUM(order_lines.accounting_total) AS Order_Total 
FROM (order_lines LEFT JOIN order_headers ON order_lines.order_header_id = order_headers.id) 
WHERE (order_headers.status LIKE 'Issued') OR (order_headers.status LIKE 'Closed') 
Group by YEAR(order_headers.created_at), QUARTER(order_headers.created_at)
```

I need to take `SUM(order_lines.accounting_total) as 'TOTAL SPEND'` without applying the year and quarter filter.

Any pointers/tips would be appreciated.

[image: Current Query Returns]

Comment: Can you show some input and expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just added screenshot.

Comment: I would like to see the _input_ data along with desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really just want the grand total of the `Order_Total` with no year or quarter aggregation, then you could try using a subquery:

```
SELECT DATABASE() AS PURCHASING_Total_PO_Value_By_Year, 
    YEAR(order_headers.created_at) AS Year, 
    QUARTER(order_headers.created_at) AS Quarter, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(order_headers.id)) AS Orders, 
    SUM(order_lines.accounting_total) AS Order_Total,
    100 * SUM(order_lines.accounting_total) /
        (SELECT SUM(accounting_total) FROM order_lists) AS Order_Percentage
FROM order_lines LEFT JOIN order_headers
    ON order_lines.order_header_id = order_headers.id
WHERE (order_headers.status LIKE 'Issued') OR (order_headers.status LIKE 'Closed')
GROUP BY YEAR(order_headers.created_at), QUARTER(order_headers.created_at)
```

The column I added to your `SELECT` is this:

```
100 * SUM(order_lines.accounting_total) /
    (SELECT SUM(accounting_total) FROM order_lists) AS Order_Percentage
```

Comment: I need to keep the total spent for that quarter/year but then I need another column showing the percentage as compared to SUM(order_lines.accounting.total) without the filters. I'm almost there-     ...`QUARTER(order_headers.created_at) AS Quarter, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(order_headers.id)) AS Orders,
 SUM(order_lines.accounting_total) AS 'SPEND',
 (('SPEND' / 'Total_Spend') * 100) as '% of Spend',
    (SELECT SUM(accounting_total) FROM order_lines) AS Total_Spend 
FROM order_lines LEFT JOIN order_headers`
 The above modifications return NULL in every range for the percentage.

Comment: I don't think you can use aliases in this way.  Please use my exact query.

Comment: I used your exact query and it returned the TOTAL Order value in the far right column. I need that value as a percentage.